# Where can I listen to live “Gypsy” music in Bucharest?

Tags: europe, romania, eastern-europe, music, bucharest

I've been living in Bucharest for a month now, and at the end of May I will receive visitors from France for a few days.

One of the fantasies they have about Romania is to listen to traditional “Gypsy” music with violins, as we understand it in Western Europe.

I'm having trouble finding anything other than Manele (which is everywhere, but I'm looking for something that sounds more like [Les Yeux Noirs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgF80aPztiI) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIH57LZn2P4)). I've read about transylvanian villages where you might find something, such as Palatca or in the Cluj-Napoca surroundings, but we won't have time to go there.

The only thing I know of in Bucharest would be the Caru Cu Bere, but the music isn't live and they switch musical genre every three songs - great restaurant, but not what I'm looking for.

Is there a place where I can listen to live Romani music (whether a bar, restaurant, street animation, club, concert location…) in Bucharest?

Comment: Cluj-Napoca is hardly a village…

Comment: @Relaxed: correct thanks, I edited that. I've read on forums the region contains villages and opportunities for gipsy-like music experiences though, but it is too far away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of restaurants that sometimes have live gypsy music.  If you got in touch with them you should be able to find out if they have any bands playing while your friends are in town (assuming this isn't too late).

- [Casa Doina](http://www.casadoina.ro/index_en.html) sometimes has them [playing in their wine cellar](http://guides.octopustravel.com/Destcontent.jsp?dest=CBUH&filename=restandbars.htm).
- Locanta Jaristea sometimes has [Taraful Cailor de Curte Veche playing](http://business-review.eu/sidebar-featured/concerted-effort-beat-the-winter-blues-with-some-live-music/).

Comment: In my research and for reference, I also stumbled upon the [casa romaneasca](http://restaurantcasaromaneasca.ro/) and [Terasa Doamnei](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294458-d1062379-Reviews-Terasa_Doamnei-Bucharest.html)... Thanks for your answer!